# Is there a way to find out the current store version of my Windows Store app?

Tags: c#, windows-8, windows-runtime, windows-store-apps, windows-8.1

I want the app to be able to check the store and see if there is an update available or not, so that I can notify my users (if they do not opt-out) that there is an update available.

I believe I can do this by hosting the current version somewhere, such as a mobile service, but I want to see if there is a way to do this on MSFT's dime, such as by querying the store somehow. Does anyone know if there is a way to do this? I bet there is a URI I can query with my App ID and parse the resulting Json feed. I've been looking in the store logs for one, but have not found one that works ideally yet.

Comment: In Windows 8.1, apps by default auto-update/install. And, it's turned on by default.

Comment: This I realize, and if that's the case then when a user opens the app, I'd like to not alert them of an update. For those that have it turned off, I'd still like to alert them, as my app is security-relevant and updates could potentially be very important.

Comment: There's no documented way to do it, and even if there was, it sounds like you might want to provide additional details/encouragement for a particular update. If you already have a web site, you could just tack it on there (it could just be a static text file that you update as needed).

Comment: That I could do, but I'd need to pay for the bandwidth (which will likely not be much, but I'd prefer not to have to do it). As to the documentation, I was hoping either a MSFT-y would chime in with either the answer or some other method, or some other curious programmer would like to join me in the search for one.

Comment: If it's not documented, then it's not supported. Myself, I'd rather pay for the TINY amount of bandwidth you're talking about than rely on an unsupported technique, especially when I think there's extra meta-data you'd want to provide for each release. It would be really inexpensive on S3 storage/month for example (or you could use something like the free tier at Heroku/OpenShift/etc to host the file and accept that you get what you pay for)

Comment: If you just manually add a version row in the description field, eg. "Version : 1.0.0.8" you could just look for that, and update it accordingly for each release. Otherwise, you might be able to do something with the meta property "<meta name="App.ReleaseGUID" content="5436ef6d-7928-4c86-a215-4214af6ecb70" />" on the web page of your app.